# How does the .awaitmessage feature work in discord js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

i'm trying to make a command where one user can challenge another user to earn coins. I've done this in a way that the person who wants to challenge is p1 and the person he @s is the p2. How can i await a message from that specific (p2) to check wether he accepts or denies? Here is my code so far.

```
    name: "duel",
    description: "Challenge a player to win extra <:kcoin:810191130385317913>",
    type: "Shop",
    minArgs: 2,
    maxArgs: 2,
    argsError: `<@user> <amount>`,
    callback: async (message, args) => {
        
        if (args < minArgs || args > maxArgs){

            message.channel.send(argsError)
            return
        }
        
        if (message.mentions.members.first() == undefined){

            message.channel.send("**Challenge someone by @ them.**")
            return
        }
        
        if (isNaN(args[1])){

            message.channel.send("**Use a number for the amount.**")
            return
        }
        
        const p1id = message.author.id 
        const p2id = message.mentions.members.first().user.id
        const amount = args[1]

        message.channel.send(`**<@${p1id}> has challenged <@${p2id}> to a duel for ${amount*2}** <:kcoin:810191130385317913>`)

        message.channel.awaitMessages({})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) for more info, but if I understand correctly, then all you have to do is create a filter.

In this case, the filter you should implement is simple. To just filter whether or not the message is from the second person, you can just do:

```js
const filter = response => {
    //this checks whether the person who wrote the message is the @ person
    return response.author.id === p2id;
};
```

This is only a simplistic filter, there's other things you can check, such as if the person who is the target has formatted it properly, and you can respond back.

As for implementing `awaitMessages`, you can follow the formatting of the [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages) has provided.

Code:

```js
const filter = response => {
    //this checks whether the person who wrote the message is the @ person
    return response.author.id === p2id;
};

message.channel.send(`**<@${p1id}> has challenged <@${p2id}> to a duel for ${amount*2}** <:kcoin:810191130385317913>`).then(() => {
    //this sets a time constraint, you can remove it, it's not required
    message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { time: 30000 /* time is in ms */, errors: ['time'] })
        .then(collected => {
            //responds back to channel that the user has responded
            message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author.username} has responded!`);
        })
        .catch(collected => {
            message.channel.send("Time to respond timed out.")
        });
});
```

Comment: I have done this and the timeout works which is useful but when i do respond the collected ```message.channel.send(`${collected.author.username} has responded!`);``` does not work

Comment: Does it give you an error? I've edited the code so instead of just `collected`, you use `collected.first()`

Comment: I get no error and even with that modification to the code it just doesn't run the code in the .then

Comment: On a line before the ```message.channel.send(`${collected.first()author.username} has responded!`);``` can you add `console.log(collected.content);` and see if there's anything in the console that prints out?

Comment: No nothing prints out it doesn't reach that line.

Comment: Are you sure you're the person who is tagged/mentioned in the message?

Comment: yes i @myself, if i console.log(filter) i get true

Comment: It's fine i just had to put a max:1 in the awaitMessages so it wouldn't wait for infinite messages but thank you for your help

Comment: That's good. In addition, you can change the time constraint so they are more limited. I had the message wait for 30 seconds so it collects all of the messages within the 30 second timeframe.